# Root account balance about my own private network and connect with stellar network

Tags: stellar-core

I have set up my own stellar private network and the root account balance of that network is 100B. This is because  as per my knowledge in the stellar-core source code the root account balance is already set.

Now if I change the configuration of stellar-core.cfg file from my private network to Stellar Test Network, whatever configurations are given in the [link](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_testnet.cfg) and start the network again from new-db and in this network setup the balance of the root account is 40.9992900 XLM. So how is this balance different from network to network, though the source code is not being changed?